# What factors (hereditary or acquired) affect the formation of tan tones and why some people lose tan earlier than other?

Tags: dermatology

I compared two people (both Russians, both have the same skin tone) after tanning.  One tan passed after 4 weeks, the other holds even after 4 months.  I do not have professional knowledge in dermatology, but I am interested in what affected the longer presence of melanin on the skin of one of the people, and in general, what factors can occur during temporary pigmentation in different people?